# How can I use the data in a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

[image: My code in Tensorflow]

As you can see in the picture, I want to compute the total cost during one training, but the `tf.equal` returns a tensor type and the `tf.equal(y1[i],y2[i])` can't be `True`.

How can I use the data in the tensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in Tensorflow (pyTorch can do something like this). The reason is, that TF requires a static graph. But you are trying to do dynamic evaluations.
Many people claim this static graph being a disadvantage of TF. But in fact, it enables many cool features. But in you use case it is a little bit cumbersome to get a solution:

You need to write it like:

```
z = tf.zeros_like(y1)
label_a = z + 2
label_b = z + 20


case_001 = tf.where(tf.equal(y1, z), z + 2, z)
case_002 = tf.where(tf.equal(y2, z), z + 20, z)
switch_op = tf.where(tf.equal(y1, y2), ..., case_001 + case_002)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I'm doing research for cost-sensitve NN. This problem had troubled me for several days. Could I ask you for help when I have problem with Tensorflow?